# MVC Controllers action methods not being referenced by Views

Tags: model-view-controller, reference, view, controllers

Sorry if this has been asked before. If it has, I cannot find an answer

None of my controllers show that they are being referenced.

My solution has a number of assemblies: the main site which references a core assembly, data assembly and a 'web' assembly.

The main website contains the views and the 'web' assembly holds the  controllers.

The question is should things in the 'web' assembly be in the same assembly as views? It is strange that in the 'web' assembly, other items in the 'web' assembly are being referenced. That is, all items other than Controllers in the 'web' assembly folder are being referenced.

There is nothing in the main website/views/web.config referencing the web assembly controllers.  i.e. controllers is not referenced in the views web.config.

There are no compile errors being generated. It is running in Framework 4.5 The MVC is version 4. I tried to make some changes with ReSharper to see if there could be a namespace issue across the projects. What it did do was try and change the folder structure in the 'web' assembly, which caused a bit of a mess and all had to be rolled back.

To get an idea of the structure, here is a shot of the solution.

[Visual Studio solution layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rahMx.jpg)

Notice how in the 'web' project, I have blacked out the names of three folder. They are the same as the 3 names in the assembly that have been blacked out. I have also tried to create a single folder with the three names separated by a dot. This layout that you see here is the only on that I have tried that compiles with no errors.

Currently, the site loads, but none of the controls/filters work. The dropdowns drop down, the tables all load with default non-filtered data, but we cannot do anything. Very much upsetting the billing department.

Any suggestions about how I might try to troubleshoot this problem would be very welcome. One week later, and I feel the writing is on the wall for me very soon!

Thank you for any help...

Comment: Haven't done it myself, I tend to stick to one project for convenience, but perhaps you need to add the following in your main project setup - `ControllerBuilder.Current.DefaultNamespaces.Add("YourNamespace.Contollers");`

Comment: Been trying to work out how/where you would add this... In the global.asax? I have tried a number of places with no joy...